# Does R's as.data.frame() correctly parse lists with Unicode names?

Tags: r

I originally posted this question thinking that there was a problem with `rjson::` but I have since concluded that `rjson::` is working fine and the problem must be with my misunderstanding of the `as.data.frame()` function.

I am using a JSON file found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nItH4WiIYYnerxSNdfcbyK07c-p-LEFU/view?usp=sharing). This is a data file with 40 observations of 35 variables. I read in the raw JSON data using `rjson::fromJSON()` which produces a length-40 list where each element is a 35-element list:

```r
raw_JSON <- rjson::fromJSON(file = "World Class.json")
```

Then, I use `as.data.frame()` to convert to a data frame, as advised by a bunch of other sources:

```r
df <- as.data.frame(raw_JSON)
```

...but this results in a data frame with 1 row and 1400 columns (1400 = 35 × 40). I have explored all the options of `as.data.frame()` and cannot find a relevant one.I have also tried an option in `fromJSON()` that uses vectors in some places rather than lists, to no avail.

I tried using `RJSONIO::` and got the same results, a 1 × 1400 data frame. Note that `jsonlite::` reads the data just fine, but my question is more about what I'm doing wrong with the list of lists; I'm not looking for a package that works.

Comment: Have I understood you correctly that your actual issue is to convert a list of lists to a data.frame (and not really about `rjson::fromJSON()`)? If so, you may show a small representative example of the list. E.g. a length-2 list (instead of length 40) where each element is a 3-element (instead of 35) list: `l = list(list(x = 1, y = "a", z = "A"), list(x = 2, y = "b", z = "B"))`. Does `do.call(rbind.data.frame, l)` provide the desired result?

Comment: I left the whole data set because it contains multitudes: Column names with parentheses, languages that are left-to-right as well as right-to-left, completely non-roman languages, and even languages that use more than one combining character with letters. This variety happens in both the column names and in the data. By the time I tried to pull out a representative sample of all that, I'd still have a big data frame. So, perhaps wrongly, I just left it whole, thinking that 40 × 35 isn't *that* big.

Comment: I didn't know until your comment that there were `data.frame` versions of `rbind` and `cbind`, and yes, your `do.call()` does work. What's mysterious to me is that so many internet sites (like top Google responses https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_json_files.htm and https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-read-json-files-in-r and some StackOverflow questions) recommend using `as.data.table()`. Can you help me understand why using `as.data.table()` is incorrect?

Comment: From `?as.data.frame`: "If a list is supplied, each element is converted to a column in the data frame". So your output makes sense. In the examples in the links in your comment, the input lists are not nested, and each list element have several values. On the other hand, in your question the input list is a nested list of lists, where each element has a single value. No, 40 * 35 is not that big. But it is better to make your question _self-contained_ - a link may be removed at any moment, which will make your question useless for future visitors. Hope this helps! Cheers.